# Why is it Segmentation fault every time?

Tags: memory

This code gives error only in runtime and it's "Segmentation fault". How can this  be tackled? I don't have any idea how to remove this error. Thanks in Advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    private:
        int     data;
        Node*   nextNodeAddress;

    public:
        Node(): nextNodeAddress(NULL) {} // if next node is not used it must be null.

        void    setData(int); // this function sets data in the node
        int     retrieveData(); // this function retrieves the data from the node
};

void Node::setData(int data)
{ this->data=data; }

class List
{
    private:
        Node* headNode;
        Node* currentNode;
        int listSize;
    public:
        List();
        void    addNode(int);
        void    deleteNode(int);
};

List::List(): headNode(NULL),currentNode(NULL)
{

}

void List::addNode(int data)
{
    Node* newNode = NULL;
    newNode->setData(data);
    newNode->setNextNode(NULL);
    if(headNode==NULL)
        headNode = newNode;
    else
        currentNode->setNextNode(newNode);
    currentNode = newNode;
    this->listSize++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GCC with all warnings on throws this:

```
In member function ‘void Node::setData(int)’:
18:28: warning: declaration of ‘data’ shadows a member of 'this' [-Wshadow]
 void Node::setData(int data)
```

Might be a good place to start checking.

Edit: The issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958457/gcc-wshadow-is-too-strict), basically you're reusing the name `data` in both `private int` in the class definition and `int data` as the parameter for the method. How could it possibly decide which one is which when you do `this->data = data`?